# Which Canvas library to choose? Fabric, Kinetic, paper

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs, fabricjs

I'm currently about to begin work on a project and I'm wondering which library is the best to use.

The project is to create a simulation of a particular scenario.  It's main requirements are:

- Animation on various parts / objects
- User input for some variable, including the constructor parameters of some objects.
- Collision detection
- Flood algorithm.
- Images will be required and the 'pattern' aspect of fabric would be perfect for a couple of objects

I'm attempting to model the Macondo well disaster.

I recently discovered Fabric js and was excited, very excited at the prospect of being able to use objects.  I then looked a bit harder and found many other libraries that are available.

I'd like to ask what the benefits of using Fabric js are over those of the alternative libraries.  From what I've described, would Fabric be able to cater to all the requirements and would an alternative framework be a better solution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: question edited to comply with SO criteria

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not meeting the SO requirements, as what is "best" is in large degree opinionated. The question should rather be about a problem you're facing with a particular code, f.ex. using fabric or some other library. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Animations are covered very well in Fabric. Collision detection — not too much; only basic stuff (whether polygon intersects with another polygon, for example). Patterns - yes, as you found out. I'm not sure what you mean by "flood" and "user input".

Comment: @kangax, thanks for the comment.  I'm currently working on the animations pat, bounding box collision should be fine for the time being but do you know if Kinetic and fabric play well together?  Could i use them both in harmony?
Flood is the algorithm I'll be working on and user input will just be buttons or sliders

Comment: Buttons and sliders can be easily hooked to modify certain object/canvas properties in Fabric. I'm not sure if Kinetic and Fabric play well together, but I can tell that in Fabric we try to encapsulate everything properly so that it plays well with other libraries. Why do you need Kinetic besides Fabric? Anything Fabric doesn't solve?

Comment: @kangax, so far I'm loving fabric. ALOT. It's pretty amazing what you've created.  I might need to use a more complicated collision detection algorithm that doesn't rely on bounding boxes.  Long way from that point yet though:)
Small question:  I know how to access single elements in a group but can I target a single element when it's not?  I'm trying to use this but only on one element :  (function animate() {
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
            obj.top += 1;

        });

Comment: There's `canvas.getObjects()` and `canvas.item(index)`. Or you can store a reference to an object. It's best if you create standalone questions here on SO or in Fabric's google group!

Comment: You'll be seeing a lot of me on the google group:)